# Update submodule before including a sub-makefile

Tags: makefile, git-submodules

I have a makefile that includes another makefile. This happens very early in the makefile. Something like:

```
include $(SOME_SDK)/Makefile.defines
```

However `SOME_SDK` is a submodule.

I would like to run `git submodule update --init --recursive` before getting to the point where the include happens.

Ideally, this should not be part of any target.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have this command as part of some target, because the `include` directive is fulfilled before any target is calculated.

But you can have any shell command (or script) executed at any place of the `Makefile`, even before the `include`.

```
dummy := $(shell git submodule update --init --recursive)
include $(SOME_SDK)/Makefile.defines
```